# How to execute a MySql stored procedure using C# Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, c, visual-studio

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in `MySql` using C#.

If I execute the stored procedure from `MySql` WorkBench, it works completely ok:

```
call  **DB.spName()**;

Time    Action  Message Duration / Fetch
```

3   1   10:46:07    call **DB.spName()**    9 row(s) returned   0.187 sec / 0.000 sec

When I execute the stored procedure from the code, there is no error, but it doesn't return any records:

```
static String sqlCnn = ";server=localhost;user id=root; database=DB; password=xxxx; Allow Zero Datetime=True; Convert Zero Datetime=True; SslMode=none;";

MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection();
Conn.ConnectionString = sqlCnn;

try
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("spName", Conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    Conn.Open();

    MySqlDataReader drAR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

I am sure that the `spName` exists and the code find it (because I changed the name, and with other name it returns error "stored procedure non-existent"), but I don't know why it's empty

Comment: Unless I'm wrong- It doesn't look like you're storing the return values anywhere, like in a `DataTable`. So when you're trying to view the data, it shows nothing because that's what is stored.

Comment: MySqlDataReader drAR = cmd.ExecuteReader()     brings a set of data ....  i have used this instruction a lot, but directly using the "select" inside ....   Never with an store-procedure

Comment: Yes, it brings a set of data. But is it storing it in a usable way? Try declaring a `DataTable table = new DataTable();` before your `try-catch` , and then after `MySqlDataReader drAR = cmd.ExecuteReader();` , add `drAR.Fill(table);` and see if that works for you :) -- I usually use SQL Server and not MySql, but they seem to be similar enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MySqlDataReader drAR = cmd.ExecuteReader();` doesn't read any of the data. You need to iterate over the returned rows as follows:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // do something with reader.GetValue(0), reader.GetString(1), etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for coments ....  i was looking for my mistakes in the sp (because it is the first time i use it), and because of your comment i realized that the mistake was on the reading instead of the execution of the sp and the retrieving of the data....  the mistake was that i was using 
`reader["ColumnName"]`

not 
`reader.GetValue(ColumnNumber)`

Now i have to solve this issue, but i think it is easier to solve .... 

Thanks a lot